# Detect default background for a custom component

Tags: codenameone

I have a component that inherits `Component` and then does it's own `paint` routine. I let the background paint itself (in a native look) and would like to alter the colours I use in the paint routine to match that background. Is it possible to find what kind of background has been chosen by the system when using a native theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f.getStyle().getBgColor();
```

Will work for forms or components (where f is the form, in this example).

Comment: Correct. Check out the developer guide section on building custom components where we explain more. E.g. padding proper usage of coordinate space etc.